# Padding integer with zeros

Tags: c#

I know I can format string with left padding with spaces with line:

```
int i=5;
serial = String.Format("{0,20}", i);
```

But how to left pad wit `0` in order to get string below?

```
00000000000000000005
```

Comment: Always 20 zeros? Or always 2 characters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the built-in function `PadLeft`:

```
int i = 5;
var result = i.ToString().PadLeft(8, '0');
```

Note: this doesn't work for negative numbers (you'd get 00000000-5).

For that you can use the built-in formatters:

```
int i = 5;
var result = string.Format("{0:D8}", i);
```